# Persist CheckBox State in Telerik MVC Grid While Paging in ASP.NET MVC Application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, grid, telerik

I am using Telerik MVC Grid where one of the columns is checkboxes. If I select checkboxes and then go to page 2 and then come back to page 1 all the checkboxes are gone. Which is of course the way HTTP works. Now, I put all the selected checkboxes inside the hidden field but since the grid does some sort of postback my hidden field is cleared next time.

Comment: Telerik: the company that makes MVC look more like WebForms. MVC is about *removing* all that leaking abstraction layer that was WebForms... and then people start using lots of heavy components above it. Next thing will be some kind of ViewState. Sorry, but I just don't get it.

Comment: @rsenna: The last time I checked, Telerik's specialty was ASP.NET components, which they do very well.  Their MVC components are really just bolt-ons for making their components work with ASP.NET MVC.  There are excellent jQuery grids available elsewhere that work very well and don't require ViewState.

Comment: @Robert Harvey: I only disagree with your first statement. I am a Telerik WebForms user, and to me their UltraWebGrid is a maintenance nightmare - even if it is filled with lots of "cool" features. The rest is obviously true.

Answer (score 11):

If you're using Client Side data binding you can use the javascript/jquery below to maintain checkbox state.

Maintain checkbox state:

```
var selectedIds = [];

$(document).ready(function () {
    //wire up checkboxes.
    $('#YOUR_GRID_ID :checkbox').live('change', function (e) {
        var $check = $(this);
        console.log($check);
        if ($check.is(':checked')) {
            //add id to selectedIds.
            selectedIds.push($check.val());
        }
        else {
            //remove id from selectedIds.
            selectedIds = $.grep(selectedIds, function (item, index) {
                return item != $check.val();
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Restore checkbox state after data binding:

```
function onDataBound(e) {
    //restore selected checkboxes.
    $('#YOUR_GRID_ID :checkbox').each(function () {
        //set checked based on if current checkbox's value is in selectedIds.
        $(this).attr('checked', jQuery.inArray($(this).val(), selectedIds) > -1);
    });
}
```

A more verbose explanation available on my blog:
http://blog.cdeutsch.com/2011/02/preserve-telerik-mvc-grid-checkboxes.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to save the state of the checkboxes to your database, and then retrieve them again from the database when you reload the page.

During paging, you need to reload only those records that pertain to a particular page.  You can do that using the `Skip()` and `Take()` methods from Linq.

Comment: I think he talks about the browser `Back` button.

Comment: I am talking about the paging buttons! I do not have access to the database. Is there anywhere else I can store the checkbox id's

Answer (score 0):

to preserve checked /unchecked checkbox state using  telerik grid clientemplate across postbacks and async postbacks and in refreshing grid and (auto)paging, I tried the solution above with no avail and so went up with a bit harder solution; as I could not save the state in db, I used a session variable and an hiddenfield:
first, a way to do ajax postback (see function DoAjaxPostAndMore , courtesy of somebody herearound), where in success we take care of client values of selections, adding and removing as checked /unchecked

I also had to manually check / uncheck the checkboxes inside the manual ajax post

second, an hidden field (see 'hidSelectedRefs') to preserve clientactions, as the Session variable I am using will not be seen clientside in partial rendering

```
    @model IEnumerable<yourInterfaceOrClass>

    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "Select Something via checkboxes";
        Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    }

    <h2>Select Something via checkboxes</h2>
    <!-- we need a form with an id, action must be there but can be an empty string -->
    <form id="frm" name ="frm"  action=""> 
    <p>
    <!--we need this as Session new values will not be takein in aajax requests clientisde, so it is easier to mange this field, which, in first and subsequent complete postbacks can have the value of the Session variable -->
        <input type="hidden" name="hidSelectedRefs" id="hidSelectedRefs" value= '@Session["SelectedReferencesToPrint"]' />  
    </p>

    <br />

    <script type="text/javascript">
       //ajax manual post to a custom action of controller, passing the id of record and the state of the checkbox
       //to adjust the Session value
       //data: $form.serialize() will have the single checbox value
       //but only if checked. To make my life eaasier, I added the value (is id ) and the checked/unchecked 
       //state of checkbox (is the $(chkClicked).attr('checked'))
        function DoAjaxPostAndMore(chkClicked) {
            var $form = $("#frm");
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: 'SelectReferences',
                data: $form.serialize() + '&id=' + $(chkClicked).val() + '&checked=' + $(chkClicked).attr('checked'),
                error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                    //do something about the error
                    alert("Sorry, we were not able to get your selection...");
                },
                success: function (response) {
                    //I also needed to check / uncheck manually the checkboxes:

                    $(chkClicked).attr('checked', !$(chkClicked).attr('checked'));

                    //and now put correct values in hidSelectedRefs hidden field:

                    if ($(chkClicked).attr('checked')) {

                        $('input[name=hidSelectedRefs]').val($('input[name=hidSelectedRefs]').val() + '|' + $(chkClicked).val() + '|');
                    } else {
                        var tmp = $('input[name=hidSelectedRefs]').val();

                        $('input[name=hidSelectedRefs]').val(tmp.toString().replace('|' + $(chkClicked).val() + '|', ''));

                    }
                }
            });

            return false; // if it's a link to prevent post
        }




Then I handled the OnRowDataBound, to ensure the checboxes would be correctly checked on postbacks,


    function onRowDataBound(e) {
            var itemsChecked = $('input[name=hidSelectedRefs]').val();


            if (itemsChecked)
            {
                if (itemsChecked.indexOf('|' + $(e.row).find('input[name=checkedRecords]').val() + '|') >= 0)
                {
                    $(e.row).find('input[name=checkedRecords]').attr('checked', true);
                }
            }
     }
     </script>

    

    The telerik mvc Grid is as follows:
    
(you can see I also handled OnDataBinding and OnDataBound, but thats's only to show a 
    "Loading" gif. The controller is named "Output" and the action that normally would be called "Index" here is callled "PrintReferences". The correspondenting Ajax action is called "_PrintReferences") 


    Of interest here is the ClientTemplate for checkbox (cortuesy of someone else herearound, where onclick
    we call our custom ajax action (named "SelectReferences") on our Output controller via a call to the
     DoAjaxPostAndMore() javascript/jquery function 

    
    @(Html.Telerik().Grid<yourInterfaceOrClass>()
                    .Name("Grid")
                        .ClientEvents(e => e.OnDataBinding("showProgress").OnDataBound("hideProgress").OnRowDataBound("onRowDataBound"))
                         .DataBinding(dataBinding =>
                         {
                             dataBinding.Server().Select("PrintReferences", "Output", new { ajax = ViewData["ajax"]});
                             dataBinding.Ajax().Select("_PrintReferences", "Output").Enabled((bool)ViewData["ajax"]);
                         })  
                    .Columns( columns =>
                        {
                            columns.Bound(o => o.ID); 
                            columns.Bound(o => o.ID)
                            .ClientTemplate(
                               "<input type='checkbox' name='checkedRecords' value='<#= ID #>'  onclick='return DoAjaxPostAndMore(this)' />"
                               )
                            .Width(30)
                            .Title("")
                            .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align:center; padding: 0px; margin: 0px;" });

                            columns.Bound(o => o.TITLE);
                            columns.Bound(o => o.JOBCODE); 
                            columns.Bound(o => o.ORDERCODE );
                            //columns.Bound(o => o.AUTHOR);
                            columns.Bound(o => o.STATE);

                            columns.Command(commands =>
                        commands
                           .Custom("Details")
                           .ButtonType(GridButtonType.Image)
                          .HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "t-icon-details" })                      
                           .DataRouteValues(route => route.Add(o => o.ID)
                              .RouteKey("ID"))
                           .Ajax(false)
                           .Action("Details", "Referenza")

                           );

                        })

                       .Pageable(paging => 
                      paging.PageSize(10)
                      .Style(GridPagerStyles.NextPreviousAndNumeric)
                      .Position(GridPagerPosition.Bottom))
                        .Sortable()
                        .Filterable()
                         .Resizable(resizing => resizing.Columns(true))
                         .Reorderable(reorder => reorder.Columns(true))
                        .NoRecordsTemplate("No Reference found. Please review your filters...")
                         .ColumnContextMenu()
                        )

    </form>




that's all for the View. Now, to the controller:


    //Get : this is the usally called "Index" action
    //here we can load data, but we also must ensure the Session variable is fine

      public ActionResult PrintReferences(bool? ajax, string msgInfo, string selectedRef)
      {
          if (Session["SelectedReferencesToPrint"] == null)
          {
              Session["SelectedReferencesToPrint"] = string.Empty;
          }
          if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(selectedRef))
          {
              selectedRef = "|0|";
          }


          string msgOut = string.Empty;

          //this is where I get data to show
          List<yourInterfaceOrClass> ret = LoadData(out msgOut);

          if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(msgInfo) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(msgInfo.Trim()))
          {
              msgOut = msgInfo + ' ' + msgOut;
          }
          ViewBag.msgOut = msgOut;

          ViewData["ajax"] = ajax ?? true;

          return View(ret);

      }

      //GridAction: here is telerik grid Ajax get request for your "_Index"
      [GridAction]
      public ActionResult _PrintReferences(string msgInfo)
      {
          //again, we must take care of Session variable
          if (Session["SelectedReferencesToPrint"] == null)
          {
              Session["SelectedReferencesToPrint"] = string.Empty;
          }
          string msgOut = string.Empty;

          List<yourInterfaceOrClass> ret = LoadData(out msgOut);
          return View(new GridModel(ret));
      }

      //Post: this is where our custom ajax post goes
      //we are here if a checkbox is cheched or unchecked
      //in the FormCollection parameter we get the checkbox value only if checked, and also 
      //(and always) the parms we passed (id of record and state of checkbox: we cannot simply add, 
      //we must also subtract unchecked) 
      [HttpPost]
      public ActionResult SelectReferences(FormCollection collection)
      {
          //we need a session variable
          if (Session["SelectedReferencesToPrint"] == null)
          {
              Session["SelectedReferencesToPrint"] = string.Empty;
          }
          //use a local variable for calculations
          string wholeSelectionToPrint = Session["SelectedReferencesToPrint"].ToString();

          //get value passed: id 
          string selectedRefId = collection["id"];
          if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(selectedRefId))
          {
              selectedRefId = "|" + selectedRefId + "|";

          }
          bool cheked = (collection["checked"].ToString()=="checked");
          //get vcalue passed :checked or unchecked


          if (cheked)
          {
              //the element is to add
              wholeSelectionToPrint += selectedRefId;
          }
          else
          {
              //the element is to remove
             wholeSelectionToPrint = wholeSelectionToPrint.Replace(selectedRefId, "");
          }


          //set session variable final value
          Session["SelectedReferencesToPrint"] = wholeSelectionToPrint;

          return null;

      }

      //normal postback:
      //we will be here if we add a button type submit in our page,
      //here we can collect all data from session variable to do
      //something with selection
      [HttpPost]
      public ActionResult PrintReferences(FormCollection collection)
      {

          //get selected references  id 
          if (Session["SelectedReferencesToPrint"] == null)
          {
              Session["SelectedReferencesToPrint"] = string.Empty;
          }
          //use a local variable for calculations
          string wholeSelectionToPrint = Session["SelectedReferencesToPrint"].ToString();
          wholeSelectionToPrint = wholeSelectionToPrint.Replace("||", "|");
          string[] selectdIDs = wholeSelectionToPrint.Split(new char[] { '|' });
          foreach (string id in selectdIDs)
          { 
              if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(id))
              {
                  //do something with single selected record ID
                  System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(id);    
              }
          }
          //omitted [....]

          ViewData["ajax"] = true;

          return View(ret);

      }
```